# Update ListView without clearing and blinking

Tags: java, android, multithreading, listview

I need refresh my listview without clearing and blinking, just show new items. But I can't do that at once, because I getting items async during a few seconds. This code doesn't work correctly by the reason of clearing adapter at the very beginning of procedure.

```
private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
    if (enable) {
        mLeDeviceListAdapterNew.clear();
        //mLeDeviceListAdapterNew.notifyDataSetChanged();

        // Stops scanning after a pre-defined scan period.
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mScanning = false;
                mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mLeDeviceListAdapterNew.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        scanLeDevice(true);
                        //invalidateOptionsMenu();
                    }
                });
            }
        }, SCAN_PERIOD);


//Here my adapter updates with new items, 
//but it's shouldn't be displayed until I call adapter 
//refresh data in SCAN_PERIOD
```

Comment: Are you actually adding things to the `ListView`? In the code you are showing us, you are only calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`. Or maybe you should show us more code.

Comment: elaborate Answer Or Describe Your ListView.

Comment: A little description of the code: it's updates my list adapter asynchronously, but I don't want clear my list before it will updates again. I wand to clear adapter items, then add some new by async and finaly update listview with new items. But code above doesn't updates my list after that.

Comment: May be the problem in recursion in the code above. Avoiding recursion work good for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can call `notifyDataSetChanged();` right after setting adapter for reflecting changes to list. for example

```
ListView modeList = new ListView(getActivity());
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter
                    .createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.PGA_Arrays,
                            R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            modeList.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

hope this can help.

Answer (score 0):

You need a setData method in your adapter to update data. Call it before `notiftyDataSetChanged`.

public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
public MyAdapter(...) {
    super(...);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    .....
    return view;

}

private void setData() {
    ...
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

Comment: This method absent in BaseAdapter

Comment: @konopko You should write it. And call it before notiftyDataSetChanged.

Comment: I guess it is doesn't matter from where to call `notiftyDataSetChanged` in main thread

Comment: @konopko you should call after setting new data before calling `setadapter`.